# Template Does not Exist. Everything is Correct Yet is not Working

Tags: django

I know it has been asked, but, this is different, please have a look below: I've just created a very simple test project, the folder structure is as such:
  [image: folder structure update]

Ignore the red marks, it's because, it was said to not detect  meta programming issues.

Just for simplicities sake, I've made the view to be called in the homepage itself, the main project urls.py has the urls:

```
"""testproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from test1.views import test1_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^$', test1_detail)
]
```

The tag_detail1 views file is just this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from test1.models import model_test1 as Model
from django.shortcuts import render

def test1_detail(request):

    tag = Model.objects.get(name__iexact='birlaman')
    return render(request,
            'test1/test.html',
            {'tag':tag})
```

The model database is just a simple one:

```
from django.db import models


class model_test1(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    age = models.TextField()
```

I've created some data in the database:

[image: database data]

The settings.py is:

```
"""
Django settings for testproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@i4=#&q%8ib7(oe7h61n5&&t8w89!4jv2#c+r!jk8%cd%)kh$-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test1',
    'test2'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The base.html is in the templates folder as configured by: **os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template')**. and It contains the simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <title>
        <head>Some head title</head>
    </title>

    <body>
        {%block content%}
            Some default content
        {%endblock%}
    </body>

</html>
```

The base_test1.html only has one line:

```
{%extends parent_template|default:"base.html"%}
```

And the test.html is only:

```
{%extends parent|default:"test1/base_test1.html"%}

{% block content %}
    <h1>test succeeded</h1>
    <p>
        The tag is: {{tag.name}}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, every file relevant for the functioning of the project is given entirely above, and everything as you may verify is in the right place. Now, if it's a bug in django 2.0, It'd be a different thing, but what in the world gives me the following error, after I hit: ./manage.py runserver

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'test1',
 'test2']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/liz/Documents/testproject/templates/test1/test.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/test1/test.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/test1/test.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback:

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/liz/Documents/testproject/test1/views.py" in test1_detail
  11.             {'tag':tag})

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/home/liz/DocFolder1/DocFolder1/Environments/django2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  19.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: test1/test.html
```

Please tell me what the problem is, it's been 2 days I've tried to figure this out, I've remade the project several times, yet it doesn't budge. There are similar problems online but the solutions mentioned don't work.

EDIT -------------------------------------------------
I added a urls.py in under test1 folder and added the codes:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from organizer.views import test1_detail



urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$', tag_detail)
]
```

and also in the main urls.py I used this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.urls import re_path, include
from test1 import urls as test1_url

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^', include(test1_url))

]
```

However, it still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to load the template from the main urls.py rather than from within the test1 app urls.py. As a result, the template loader isn't looking in test1/templates.

Note in the error message:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/liz/Documents/testproject/templates/test1/test.html (Source does not exist)
```

Call the view from within the app or move the template the testproject/templates folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your files seem to be in a directory called "template", not "templates".

Comment: Where do you think is the part of the source code in doc that makes django scan the settings.py?

Comment: Nope, that was not the problem, I fixed it back to templates and tried it, and it doesn't budge.